# Returning Dates In A Formatted Format (Iteration)

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create tabs with each tab name being the date of the start of each week in the year. So, "Jan 01" then "Jan 08" then "Jan 14" etc.

Essentially, taking x date then adding +7 days and returning that value as a date 7 days from x date.

```js
function CreateWeekTabs(){
  var TotalsSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Totals");
  var StartingWeek = new Date(TotalsSheet.getRange("B1").getValue());  //Typically always "Jan 01" shwon. Cell Formatting is MMM DD.   Cell Value is 01/01/2019
  var CurrentWeek = new Date();
  var NextWeek = new Date();
  spreadsheet.toast("Please wait...","Creating Tabs");
  
  for (var WeekNum = 1;WeekNum <= 2;WeekNum++){ 
    
  var DayIncrease = 7 - (7 * WeekNum);   //Should produce 0,7,14,21,28.... So first iteration won't increase any value from Jan 01.
    
    CurrentWeek.setDate(StartingWeek.getDate()+DayIncrease); //E.g. First Iteration = Jan 01 + 0 = Jan 01; Second Iteration = Jan 01 + 7 = Jan 08;
    NextWeek.setDate(CurrentWeek.getDate()+7);   //Should be +7 days from CurrentWeek Value.
    

    var WeekSheetName = Utilities.formatDate(NextWeek,spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"MMM DD"); //Should return the date formatted.
   
    Logger.log(WeekNum+" -   "+WeekSheetName);
  }
}
```

With Each Iteration, I intend to create WorkSheets with the First Date of each Week Starting from Value of CurrentWeek

Eg: Jan 01, Jan 08, Jan 15, Jan 22, Jan 29, Feb 05, etc...

UPDATE:

I since changed the code to:

```js
function CreateWeekTabs(){
  var TotalsSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Totals");
  var CurrentWeek = new Date(TotalsSheet.getRange("B1").getValue());  //Typically always "Jan 01" shown. Cell Formatting is MMM dd.   Cell Value is 01/01/2019
//  var CurrentWeek = new Date();
  var NextWeek = new Date();
  spreadsheet.toast("Please wait...","Creating Tabs");
  
  for (var WeekNum = 1;WeekNum <= 12;WeekNum++){ 
    
  var DayIncrease = (7 * WeekNum) - 7;   //Should produce 0,7,14,21,28.... So first iteration won't increase any value from Jan 01.
    
    CurrentWeek.setDate(CurrentWeek.getDate()+DayIncrease); //E.g. First Iteration = Jan 01 + 0 = Jan 01; Second Iteration = Jan 01 + 7 = Jan 08;
    NextWeek.setDate(CurrentWeek.getDate()+DayIncrease+7);   //Should be +7 days from CurrentWeek Value.
    

    var WeekSheetName = Utilities.formatDate(NextWeek,spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"MMM dd"); //Should return the date formatted.
    Logger.log("Week Number: "+WeekNum+" -  Current Week: "+Utilities.formatDate(CurrentWeek,spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"MMM dd")+"    Next Week: "+WeekSheetName);
  }
}
```

and the Log is producing the following as outputs. (so I can see what it's producing for Variables 'CurrentWeek' and 'NextWeek'

```html
[19-06-14 14:40:00:463 EDT] Week Number: 1 -  Current Week: Jan 01    Next Week: Jun 08
[19-06-14 14:40:00:464 EDT] Week Number: 2 -  Current Week: Jan 08    Next Week: Jun 22
[19-06-14 14:40:00:464 EDT] Week Number: 3 -  Current Week: Jan 22    Next Week: Jul 13
[19-06-14 14:40:00:465 EDT] Week Number: 4 -  Current Week: Feb 12    Next Week: Aug 09
[19-06-14 14:40:00:466 EDT] Week Number: 5 -  Current Week: Mar 12    Next Week: Sep 16
[19-06-14 14:40:00:467 EDT] Week Number: 6 -  Current Week: Apr 16    Next Week: Oct 28
[19-06-14 14:40:00:468 EDT] Week Number: 7 -  Current Week: May 28    Next Week: Dec 16
[19-06-14 14:40:00:468 EDT] Week Number: 8 -  Current Week: Jul 16    Next Week: Feb 10
[19-06-14 14:40:00:469 EDT] Week Number: 9 -  Current Week: Sep 10    Next Week: Apr 13
[19-06-14 14:40:00:470 EDT] Week Number: 10 -  Current Week: Nov 12    Next Week: Jun 21
[19-06-14 14:40:00:471 EDT] Week Number: 11 -  Current Week: Jan 21    Next Week: Sep 06
[19-06-14 14:40:00:471 EDT] Week Number: 12 -  Current Week: Apr 07    Next Week: Nov 30
```

Why the blazes? Current Value is calculating correctly, but the value of Next Week is way off, it should be showing +7 days from Current Week.

Comment: Use format `'MMM dd'` instead.

Comment: I tried this; it didn't solve unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

The first calculates the start of week tab name for this week.  You can pick the start of week day Sun-Sat is 0-6.  The second calculates the start of week tab name for next week.

```
function thisWeeksStartOfWeekTabname(sow){
  var sow=sow || 1;//Sun-0, Sat=6
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dt=new Date();
  while(dt.getDay()>0) {
    dt=new Date(dt.setDate(dt.getDate()-1));
  }
  dt=new Date(dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+sow));
  Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(dt, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM dd"));
  return Utilities.formatDate(dt, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM dd");
}  

function nextWeeksStartOfWeekTabname(sow){
  var sow=sow || 1;//Sun-0, Sat=6
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dt=new Date();
  while(dt.getDay()>0) {
    dt=new Date(dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+1));
  }
  dt=new Date(dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+sow));
  Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(dt, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM dd"));
  return Utilities.formatDate(dt, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM dd");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So, I'm used to VBA in Excel, which seems so much easier, you literally just put Date() + x  as per how  many days you want added.
  
On this same logic, why doesn't Google Scipt understand:  
  
NewDate=new Date(oldDate.setDate(oldDate.getDate()+[NUMBER OF DAYS TO INCREASE]));  
  
why do you have to tell Google Script to do it the long way round by calculating each day and telling it (as in your example) I only want Monday's value.

Comment: There's a lot  of ways to do many things.  Most of the time I choose a way that's easy for me to understand.  In this case, I wasn't sure which first day of the week  you wanted so I thought making it flexible would be more useful for everyone.  I've used VBA for a long time in Excel it's okay.

Comment: Ahh okaym understood; appreciated. in this case, I only need to find out Monday's but I like the code. thanks.

Comment: How would I use this code to 'return' the monday's date of a given week?

for example, let says i want to create 3 tabs, starting from monday of next week - and I want to return the monday's date of each week after?

Comment: Using `thisWeeksStartOfWeekTabname(sow)` set dt= to some date inside the desired week and set sow (start of week) to whatever you want sunday = 0 and saturday = 6.